502 Bad Gateway on Nginx with Laravel, PHP 8.3, and Ubuntu 24.04
I’ve set up Nginx 1.24.0 on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, installed PHP 8.3 (PHP 8.3.6), and deployed a fresh Laravel 11.2 project. I created a virtual host on port 82 for telegrambot.test. However, when I try to access http://telegrambot.test:82, I get a 502 Bad Gateway error.
Here's my Nginx config (nginx.conf):
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                                        html htm shtml;
    text/css                                         css;
    text/xml                                         xml;
    image/gif                                        gif;
    image/jpeg                                       jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                           js;
    application/atom+xml                             atom;
    application/rss+xml                              rss;

    text/mathml                                      mml;
    text/plain                                       txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor                 jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                                 wml;
    text/x-component                                 htc;

    image/avif                                       avif;
    image/png                                        png;
    image/svg+xml                                    svg svgz;
    image/tiff                                       tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                               wbmp;
    image/webp                                       webp;
    image/x-icon                                     ico;
    image/x-jng                                      jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                                   bmp;

    font/woff                                        woff;
    font/woff2                                       woff2;

    application/java-archive                         jar war ear;
    application/json                                 json;
    application/mac-binhex40                         hqx;
    application/msword                               doc;
    application/pdf                                  pdf;
    application/postscript                           ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                                  rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl                    m3u8;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml             kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz                 kmz;
    application/vnd.ms-excel                         xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject                    eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint                    ppt;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics      odg;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation  odp;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet   ods;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text          odt;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
                                                     pptx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                                                     xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                                                     docx;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc                         wmlc;
    application/wasm                                 wasm;
    application/x-7z-compressed                      7z;
    application/x-cocoa                              cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff                  jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file                     jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                           run;
    application/x-perl                               pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                              prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed                     rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager             rpm;
    application/x-sea                                sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash                    swf;
    application/x-stuffit                            sit;
    application/x-tcl                                tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert                       der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall                          xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                            xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                             xspf;
    application/zip                                  zip;

    application/octet-stream                         bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream                         deb;
    application/octet-stream                         dmg;
    application/octet-stream                         iso img;
    application/octet-stream                         msi msp msm;

    audio/midi                                       mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                                       mp3;
    audio/ogg                                        ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                                      m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                                ra;

    video/3gpp                                       3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                                       ts;
    video/mp4                                        mp4;
    video/mpeg                                       mpeg mpg;
    video/ogg                                        ogv;
    video/quicktime                                  mov;
    video/webm                                       webm;
    video/x-flv                                      flv;
    video/x-m4v                                      m4v;
    video/x-matroska                                 mkv;
    video/x-mng                                      mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                                   asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                                   wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                                  avi;
}

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    # location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf:

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_USER        $remote_user;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/telegrambot:
server {
    listen 82;
    listen [::]:82;

    server_name telegrambot.test;

    root /var/www/telegrambot/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    charset utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params:

fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_USER        $remote_user;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/tutorial:
server {
       listen 81;
       listen [::]:81;

       server_name example.ubuntu.com;

       root /var/www/tutorial;
       index index.html;

       location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }
}

My /etc/hosts file is configured as follows:
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       Amyr-Linux
127.0.0.1       telegrambot.test

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

I installed a fresh Laravel application under /var/www/telegrambot and set the public folder as the document root. I expected to be able to access the Laravel app by visiting http://telegrambot.test:82, but instead, I got a 502 Bad Gateway error.
My /var/log/nginx/error.log output:
2024/09/24 21:00:35 [error] 58482#58482: *4 open() "/home/amyr/Desktop/Sites/telbot/public/favicon.ico" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "telegrambot:82", referrer: "http://telegrambot:82/"
2024/09/24 21:00:37 [error] 58485#58485: *5 directory index of "/var/www/telbot/public/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telbot, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:85"
2024/09/24 21:14:24 [error] 61674#61674: *2 directory index of "/var/www/telbot/public/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telbot, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "telbot:85"
2024/09/24 21:20:52 [error] 61673#61673: *3 directory index of "/var/www/telbot/public/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telbot, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "telbot:85"
2024/09/24 21:44:11 [error] 71158#71158: *2 directory index of "/var/www/telbot/public/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telbot, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "telbot:85"
2024/09/24 22:26:27 [crit] 83369#83369: *3 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test:81"
2024/09/24 22:29:15 [crit] 84798#84798: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test:81"
2024/09/24 22:29:19 [crit] 84799#84799: *3 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test:81"
2024/09/24 22:29:20 [crit] 84801#84801: *5 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test:81"
2024/09/24 22:29:20 [crit] 84800#84800: *7 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test:81"
2024/09/24 22:32:35 [crit] 84803#84803: *9 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test:81"
2024/09/24 22:32:36 [crit] 84804#84804: *11 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test:81"
2024/09/24 22:33:03 [crit] 84804#84804: *11 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test:81"
2024/09/24 23:25:47 [crit] 84805#84805: *14 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test:81"
2024/09/24 23:26:11 [crit] 90146#90146: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test:81"
2024/09/24 23:27:14 [crit] 90436#90436: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test:81"
2024/09/24 23:27:40 [crit] 90623#90623: *2 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test"
2024/09/24 23:35:20 [crit] 93355#93355: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test"
2024/09/24 23:35:21 [crit] 93356#93356: *3 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test"
2024/09/24 23:35:58 [crit] 93614#93614: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test"
2024/09/25 01:01:58 [crit] 107195#107195: *3 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test"
2024/09/25 01:01:59 [crit] 107196#107196: *5 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test"
2024/09/25 01:02:33 [crit] 107197#107197: *7 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test"
2024/09/25 01:02:35 [crit] 107198#107198: *9 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test"
2024/09/25 01:06:52 [crit] 107199#107199: *11 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test"
2024/09/25 01:16:07 [crit] 112771#112771: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test"
2024/09/25 01:17:09 [crit] 113375#113375: *2 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:82"
2024/09/25 01:17:11 [crit] 113378#113378: *4 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:82"
2024/09/25 01:48:35 [crit] 121423#121423: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:82"
2024/09/25 01:48:37 [crit] 121424#121424: *3 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:82"
2024/09/25 01:57:44 [crit] 121427#121427: *5 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:82"
2024/09/25 02:02:05 [crit] 2658#2658: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:82"
2024/09/25 02:02:35 [crit] 2660#2660: *3 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:82"
2024/09/25 02:02:37 [crit] 2661#2661: *5 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:82"
2024/09/25 02:03:06 [crit] 2659#2659: *7 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test:82"
2024/09/25 11:20:33 [crit] 2854#2854: *4 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: telegrambot.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "telegrambot.test:82"

After reviewing my configuration, I noticed that the fastcgi_pass directive in my Nginx configuration is pointing to the PHP 7.4 FPM socket, while I am using PHP 8.3. I think this might be the root cause of the issue.
I ran the following command to check for the correct PHP 8.3 FPM socket:
sudo find /var/run/php/ -name "php8.3-fpm.sock"

Based on the result, I updated my Nginx configuration to:
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;

However, the problem persists, and I am still getting the 502 Bad Gateway error. I also confirmed that both the Nginx and PHP-FPM services are running correctly.
I've tried a simple php script (phpinfo()) and it works perfect
I'm expecting Laravel to load properly when I access http://telegrambot.test:82, but instead, I keep getting this gateway error. Any suggestions on what else I should check or configure?

Which of the error lines are current? If you really use PHP 8.3, why does the log contain so many lines mentioning other PHP versions? And did you ensure that Laravel itself doesn't throw any error?

Please provide your latest config files and error logs (nginx's and php's). Did the simple php script work on :82 server?

@NicoHaase v8.3 is the correct one.
